# Laplacian in tensor

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor

Find $\vec \nabla^2\phi $ when 
$$ds^{2}=-dt^{2}+a^{2}(t)[dx^{2}+dy^{2}+dz^{2}] $$ 
or $$g_{ij}=\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 &0  &0 \\ 
0 &a^{2}(t)  &0  &0 \\ 
 0&0  &a^{2}(t)  &0 \\ 
0 &0  &0  & a^{2}(t)
\end{bmatrix}$$
I am using this relation $$\vec \nabla^2\phi=\frac{1}{\sqrt{g}}\frac{\partial }{\partial x^{k}}[\sqrt{g}g^{kr}\frac{\partial \phi }{\partial x^{r}}]$$ to calculate the laplacian but I am struggling here since if I calculate the determinant (g), it will give me $-a^{6}(t)$, so if I calculate $\sqrt{g}$, it will give me a complex number which is impossible. Also, even though I calculate $g_{11},g_{22},g_{33},g_{44}$, I won't to be able to find $x^{1},x^{2},x^{3},x^{4}$ as I don't know which coordinate system is it and hence don't know its coordinates.

Comment: And your question is? (Note that $\sqrt{g}$ is commonly understood as $\sqrt{\lvert g \rvert}$.)

Comment: What about $x^{1},x^{2},x^{3},x^{4}$ then ?

Comment: I don't understand what you want to know. Using the metric as given, your coordinates are $(t,x,y,z)$. What's the question?